# If there is dummy voter, then SSI(A) and BI(A)=0??

Tags: game-theory

for Shapley–Shubik power index and banzhaf power index,

If there is dummy voter A, then SSI(A) and BI(A) have got to be 0?

is there any counter example to it?

I think there is no counter example to it.

because if Either one of them is not equal to zero, then there might be some coalitions where Dummy voter A is pivotal, but It is against the definition of dummy.

anyone?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche But this version has more input from the OP... I voted to close the other one instead.

Comment: You are correct, a dummy voter always has a power index of zero, both for Shapley-Shubik/Banzhaf.